# Is it bad practice to use hidden fields?

Tags: javascript, html, hidden-field

A fellow programmer told me it was 'bad practice' to use hidden fields in my HTML code. Essentially I have a unordered list that a user selects an item based on a category they selected (the categories are pictures). It then calls javascript to set a hidden field to the value the user selected so I can send it along when the form submitted. Is this truly bad practice, is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: Maybe you should ask him/her first why he/she thinks so...

Comment: It's only really "bad practice" if you're trying to hide something from the user (like you're going to submit their email address over HTTP without telling them). There's nothing wrong with making use of hidden fields if it's appropriate.

Comment: Not bad practice, common practice. Depending on the implementation, you could have accessibility issues, but I would suggest you ignore your colleague or get more details from him.

Comment: If you need to persist some type of data that should be sent along with a form then use hidden fields. If it doesn't need to be sent back and may need to only be used by javascript, store it as a data-attribute.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski He didnt really have an answer for me. So I was just curious and decided to post it for discussion to see what others thought.

Comment: Questions like “Is it bad practice...” tend to solicit debate, arguments, polling, and extended discussion, instead of answers that can be agreed on and are based on facts, references, and specific expertise. This is particularly true if the question is unqualified and does not specify context and criteria to be used.

Answer (score 8):

hidden fields exist so one can set a value in a form without displaying an input, i fail to understand how it is bad practice to use them. if you need to create a custom widget and send it's value via a form it is the easiest way to do it , you could still use select buttons with dynamic select lists but you'll have to do ugly hacks to make the interface look pretty.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very common practice. The only issue I can think of in your case is that it'll break if your visitor has JavaScript disabled, so you might want a fallback.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to submit a form and need to pass a few simple values which aren't contained in visible form fields, then a hidden field is probably the oldest, most reliable, and cleanest way of doing so.

Consider the alternatives:

1. Useless: Don't pass anything hidden.
2. Poor: Abstractions, like ASP.Net viewstate which uses a hidden field anyway but pollutes the request model (and can add a bunch of unneeded data unless you are careful--and most people aren't).
3. BAD: Pass all form values on the query string. This is usually non-RESTful and can be downright harmful (user bookmarks a querystring which performs an unexpected action).
4. Maybe: Manually POST values using AJAX. This can be a very valid implementation, assuming that you only want to perform an async operation.
5. Maybe: Full roundtrip where the server handles the change (may be the only way to support users without JavaScript).

Answer (score 3):

It is bad practice to use hidden fields for information that must be secure.  When there is no security issue, it is generally fine to use hidden fields.

Comment: you should provide reasons and references.

Comment: What stop in you from encrypt them ? This is no argument because this is the same problem for any data on the page on any control or field.

Comment: It is not the standard of StackOverflow that you need to provide references.  So valentinas comment is objectively false.

Two more things: I am defending the null hypothesis that there is no problem so it is difficult to prove.  Also, it is a common-sensical type issue.

Now, it is not wrong to use hidden fields; they exist for a reason.  They are a great convenience and they are almost to use when the state of the next request is contained in the particular page you are on.  (For example, sorting of a list).

Comment: You can encrypt, but the user might be able to defeat the encryption.  If you are going through the trouble of encryption, you should probably just use a token to some sort of server-side cache that holds the data.  

This is much more secure as there is no possibility of decryption.  It is probably easier and less error prone as well.

Comment: He never stated that he was passing sensitive information, for instance i can use an input hidden to store the id of a color that an user has selected on a DOM element, why would that be a bad practice? that value will never compromise the site security.

Comment: basically correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a bad practice to store javascript value in HTML DOM. You should try to create a list stored in your javascript environement.

```
window.myList = new Array();
```

I recommend you to use something like [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or even [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) when you have a lot of stuff.

If you only use these data on the submit, your case seems legit.

Comment: "If you only use these data on the submit" Well, that would be an accessibility downside if the same functionality does not work without JS, but then again that depends on what the customer wants.